# Uuser to be logged out after certain time period of inactivity using simple_jwt in django rest framework

Tags: python, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am using django rest framework and trying to implement a security solution. The user has to login again after certain time period of inactivity.

Right now I am trying to manipulate django rest framework's settings and I updated the `REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME`

**settings.py**

```
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=30),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': False,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': True,
    'UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN': False,

    'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'SIGNING_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
    'VERIFYING_KEY': None,
    'AUDIENCE': None,
    'ISSUER': None,

    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',),
    'AUTH_HEADER_NAME': 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION',
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',

    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
    'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': 'token_type',

    'JTI_CLAIM': 'jti',

    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_EXP_CLAIM': 'refresh_exp',
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
}
```

Comment: The settings you have already made are doing this I couldn't understand the question you asked? `'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5), 'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=30),`

Comment: But this would log the user ou regardless of activity. Like if the user is currently doing any activity, then the user should not be logged out. However if the user is inactive for 30 minutes only then should the user be logged out completely.

Comment: I see but following user activity from the backend can be much more difficult than doing it on the frontend. If users' requests are cached before reaching the backend, or if they take an action that does not require them to send a request to the backend, they can log out even if they are active. I guess Simple JWT doesn't have such a built-in functionality.

Comment: Since you are using JWT, I assumed the frontend is a separate app. Anyway if you want to do this in the backend, maybe you can add a datetime field such as last_activity to the user model and add a [custom middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware) to calculate inactivity time.

Comment: I was confused about what these sliding tokens mean. Do they have any relation with the token refresh expiry time?